# GeoServer refuses startup after security updates

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

On an Ubuntu 16.04 a GeoServer 2.14.3 instance worked without problems published by Tomcat. After running `unattended-upgrades` GeoServer refuses to startup. My guess is that Package: `libtomcat8-java` or `tomcat8` has been updated which causes problems.

**Java Version:**

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

**Tomcat Version**
8.0.32

**Java Opts (in /etc/default/tomcat8):**

```
GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="/data/geoserver-data"
GEOSERVER_LOG_LOCATION="/data/geoserver-logs/geoserver.log"
GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR="/data/gwc_cache_dir"
GEOFENCE_DIR="$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/geofence"

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=128m -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Duser.timezone=GMT -Dorg.geotools.shapefile.datetime=true -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.timezone=GMT -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.servlet.response.encoding=UTF-8 -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR -Dgeofence.dir=$GEOFENCE_DIR -DGEOSERVER_LOG_LOCATION=$GEOSERVER_LOG_LOCATION -DGEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR=$GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR"
```

**Catalina.out**

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@653a0a9e]) and a value of type [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl] (value [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jan 29, 2021 3:08:17 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal.SuppliedThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal@69cce781]) and a value of type [org.geowebcache.storage.CompositeBlobStore.StoreSuitabilityCheck] (value [EXISTING]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Full catalina.out logs here: https://0bin.net/paste/vhTcUrZ9#8QCsrd9U-XO8TxcWQmWu6uPbEX7lP/D9a5JjY5d9qbw

**geoserver.log**

```
Error creating bean with name 'geoWebCacheExtensions': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
```

Full geoserver.logs here: https://0bin.net/paste/2k4iAlzZ#sPZrPiNIFk5mtUOh4ndZQkpKsUfklTCDfrUHsPCs9vt

How can I get GeoServer up and running again? (I know that the current version is 2.18.2)

Comment: Are you sure those are "full logs"? There seems to be little trace of the startup, most it's actually shutdown phase, and there is no trace of the (expectedly very long) stack trace talking about the Spring initialization failure.

Comment: @AndreaAime Thank you very much for coming to help! My apologies, you are right. It looks a part was missing. I've updated the pastebin with full catalina.log (truncated before startup): This does cover the whole startup process: https://0bin.net/paste/vhTcUrZ9#8QCsrd9U-XO8TxcWQmWu6uPbEX7lP/D9a5JjY5d9qbw If you can spot something I'm all open ears!

Comment: @AndreaAime And also the updated geoserver.log. https://0bin.net/paste/2k4iAlzZ#sPZrPiNIFk5mtUOh4ndZQkpKsUfklTCDfrUHsPCs9vt Note: The logs show a startup with disabled data directory var in Java_opts to use the one shipped with geoserver and rule out problems with  the data dir same story. geoserver refuses to start.

Comment: I don't see anything relevant there. I know that the specific GeoServer version does not work with java 8 greater than 1.8.0.255, but you say you're on ".201" so...

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @AndreaAime – I will stop to find the reason and just migrate the data to a newer GeoServer instance